# How to change the character encoding of .R file in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to save all .R file in one type of encoding, it is inconvenient to switch encodings everytimes I open a file, so, how to change the character encoding of .R file in RStudio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this. Go in "File" menu and then "Save with encoding..."

Answer (score 10):

R 3.4.3; RStudio 1.1.383

Tools > Global Options > Code > Saving > "Default text encoding" [Change]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`Tools` - `Options` - `General` - `Default text encoding:`

[image]

Comment: this no longer appears as of RStudio 1.1.383 - where is it now?