# How to change the encoding of R files

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio

I want to change the encoding of some R files directly in Rstudio.
I though you can by going to Tools > Global Options > General but the option isn't here.

That's sure it was here before because I found this post, which describe the way to do this. But, actually, this option is not here anymore.

[How to change the character encoding of .R file in RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579245/how-to-change-the-character-encoding-of-r-file-in-rstudio)

Someone knows where I can find it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for either "File > Reopen with Encoding" or "File > Save with Encoding". If the source file already is in the other encoding, then re-open it, but if you want to change it *into* the other encoding, then choose "Save with encoding".