# How to read hangul-script shapefiles into R/sf

Tags: r, character-encoding, cjk, r-sf

*Hangul* (Korean) script in shapefiles gets mangled in the process of reading into R.

Download Seoul, Incheon, Gyeonggi-do region shapefiles from [this website](http://data.nsdi.go.kr/dataset/15144) (in Korean). I [attach the files](http://www.filedropper.com/koreasca), as they are not accessible outside Korea.

I'm using RStudio on Windows 10 in English. Just in case, [set RStudio default text encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48242081/7114709) to "UTF-8" and set locale to Korean:

```
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale = "Korean")
```

Read shapefiles into R using the `sf` package:

```
library(sf)

#Read, name and combine regions
sca_nsdi <- rbind(cbind(st_read("LARD_ADM_SECT_SGG_11.shp"), Name="Seoul"), 
                  cbind(st_read("LARD_ADM_SECT_SGG_28.shp"), Name="Incheon"), 
                  cbind(st_read("LARD_ADM_SECT_SGG_41.shp"), Name="Gyeonggi-do"))

#View result
View(sca_nsdi)
```

[image]

The *hangul* in column `SGG_NM` is unreadable, as well as through the console:

```
sca_nsdi$SGG_NM[1]
```

> [1] ������

Answer (score 1):

I've finally just figured it out:

```
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale = "Korean")
sca_nsdi <- rbind(cbind(st_read("LARD_ADM_SECT_SGG_11.shp", options="ENCODING=EUC-KR"), Name="Seoul"), 
                  cbind(st_read("LARD_ADM_SECT_SGG_28.shp", options="ENCODING=EUC-KR"), Name="Incheon"), 
                  cbind(st_read("LARD_ADM_SECT_SGG_41.shp", options="ENCODING=EUC-KR"), Name="Gyeonggi-do"))
```

Comment: Setting the locale to Korean seems to stabilise the solution.