# View(kwic) with Umlaut

Tags: r, encoding, quanteda

I am having trouble with Umlauts when I am using the View(kwic(x)) command. If I am looking at the kwich output in R directly, the umlauts are show in the correct way.

```
kwic(corp_bp, digital_dictionary, window = 10)
```

Output:

```
[text23, 2148] zur Information und Präsentation. Informationsrecherche analoge und digitale Medien |          digitale          |
```

When I am using the View command for a nicer representation, the Umlauts get lost:

```
View(kwic(corp_bp, digital_dictionary, window = 10))
```

Output:

```
text23  2146    2146    mediale Quellen zur Information und PrÃ¤sentation . Informationsrecherche analoge und   digitale
```

I tried using

```
View(kwic(corp_bp, digital_dictionary, window = 10), encode = "latin1")
```

(Argument not used)

and I also tried Encoding the kwic before viewing it. Which doesn't work, because the kwic is not a character vector.

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: did you try to change the general encoding of your script like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579245/how-to-change-the-character-encoding-of-r-file-in-rstudio

Comment: I checked that already. If I look at the kwic output in R, everyhting is fine, if I use View to watch in the browser, it doesnt work anymore. So something happens when I "export" outside of R.

Comment: maybe this works then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402307/export-utf-8-bom-to-csv-in-r

i remember i had a similar problem exporting greek characters for a math project but i can't for the life of me remember what i did about it. it is solvable though